# SignalR 2.x does not work sometime on IIS (windows 2012 R2)

Tags: signalr

I want to use the signalr to push message from server to all clients in real-time,and I implement it in vs2013 and run very well locally, but after deploying to another server (windows 2012 R2), it is not very stable, sometime work, sometime not work and there is no error thrown out. 
This is my server code:

```
IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>().Clients;
Clients.All.notifiy("hello, the world");
```

And client script is and I use notify plugin display message:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();

var hub = connection.createHubProxy("MessageHub");
hub.on("notifiy", function (message) {
    $.notify({
        title: '<strong>Heads up!</strong>',
        message: message
    }, {
        type: 'success',
        offset: 20,
        spacing: 10,
        z_index: 1031,
        delay: 5000,
        timer: 1000,
        animate: {
            enter: 'animated fadeInDown',
            exit: 'animated fadeOutUp'
        },
        placement: {
            from: "bottom",
            align: "right"
        }
    });
})

connection.start();
```

Could anybody help me about this?

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work? What are the symptoms? What does browser developer tool indicate in the Network tab? This can be useful to the audience to help you identify the problem

Comment: I've set up a number of similar systems without an issue like this. All I can think of might be WebSockets limiting submissions to 64kb (see MaxIncomingWebSocketMessageSize setting). Could it be you've disconnected at that point (and failing to reconnect)? A bit unlikely...